# Denwer Ошибка №1064

Tags: denwer

Есть:
sql база мыл.

Надо: выбрать мужчин старше 30 из IT, например, сохранить в отельный документ.

Запрос:

```
SELECT concat(user.firstName,':',user_email.email) FROM user,user_email where user.userID=user_email.userID and user.gender='MALE' and user.countryISO='IT' and user.birthdate < DATE_SUB( CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 30 YEAR ) and user.birthdate > DATE_SUB( CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 80 YEAR ) order by user.dateadd DESC into outfile ‘C:/IT_MALE.txt’;
```

Пишет ошибку `:#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '‘C:/BV_MALE.txt’' at line 1`

Стоит денвер. Помогите решить проблему.

Comment: Файл создан? Путь прописан верно? Попробуйте писать в файл в корне проекта: ... into outfile 'IT_MALE.txt';

Comment: @makbeth, там ошибка синтаксиса SQL. До создания файла никто не доходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может, проблема в кавычках у `C:/IT_MALE.txt`? Попробуйте их заменить на одинарные.

Comment: @makbeth, спасибо,помогло! поменял одинарные на двойные